# Wordpress with Genesis framework, how do I change the output of an archive page for a custom content type?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, genesis

I have an archive page for a custom content type, and I want to display one of the custom fields in the archive listing. Im not sure what hook to use or how to access the variables in the custom content type to display in -archive.php. Can anyone help me out with the relevant hooks, or how to access those field variables?

Answer (score 0):

First create archive file with your custom post type, the file name should be like this **archive-{post_type}.php**

**Go through the below code this may help you**

```
<?php

remove_action ('genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop'); // Remove the standard loop
add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'custom_do_grid_loop' ); // Add custom loop
function custom_do_grid_loop() { 

 // Intro Text (from page content)
 echo '<div class="page hentry entry">';
 echo '<h1 class="entry-title">'. get_the_title() .'</h1>';
 echo '<div class="entry-content">' . get_the_content() ;
 $args = array(
 'post_type' => 'custom post type', // enter your custom post type
 'orderby' => 'menu_order',
 'order' => 'ASC',
 'posts_per_page'=> '12', // overrides posts per page in theme settings
 );
 $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
 if( $loop->have_posts() ):

 while( $loop->have_posts() ): $loop->the_post(); global $post;
 echo '<div id="testimonials">';
 echo '<div class="one-fourth first">';
 echo '<div class="quote-obtuse"><div class="pic">'. get_the_post_thumbnail( $id, array(150,150) ).'</div></div>';
 echo '<div style="margin-top:20px;line-height:20px;text-align:right;"><cite>'.genesis_get_custom_field( '_cd_client_name' ).'</cite><br />'.genesis_get_custom_field( '_cd_client_title' ).'</div>';
 echo '</div>'; 
 echo '<div class="three-fourths" style="border-bottom:1px solid #DDD;">';
 echo '<h3>' . get_the_title() . '</h3>';
 echo '<blockquote><p>' . get_the_content() . '</p></blockquote>'; 
 echo '</div>';
 echo '</div>';

 endwhile;

 endif;

 echo '</div><!-- end .entry-content -->';
 echo '</div><!-- end .page .hentry .entry -->';
}

/** Remove Post Info */
remove_action('genesis_before_post_content','genesis_post_info');
remove_action('genesis_after_post_content','genesis_post_meta');

genesis();
?>
```